# How to get date picture created in java

Tags: java, date

I would like to extract the date a jpg file was created.  Java has the lastModified method for the File object, but appears to provide no support for extracting the created date from the file.  I believe the information is stored within the file as the date I see when I hover the mouse pointer over the file in Win XP is different than what I can get by using JNI with "dir /TC" on the file in DOS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The information is stored within the image  in a format called [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) or [link text](http://www.exif.org). There several libraries out there capable of reading this format, like [this one](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/)

Comment: Great!  Thanks for all of the helpful comments!  I believe I will use the library at drewnoakes.com.

Comment: Exchangeable image file format (officially Exif, **not EXIF** according to JEIDA/JEITA/CIPA specifications) is a standard that...

Answer (score 6):

The date is stored in the [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data in the jpeg. There's a [java library](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) and a [viewer in java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexifviewer/) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I use this metadata library: http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Seems to work pretty well, although bear in mind that not all JPEG images have this information, so it can't be 100% fool-proof.

If the EXIF metadata doesn't contain the created date, then you'll probably have to make do with Java's lastUpdated - unless you want to resort to Runtime.exec(...) and using system functions to find out (I wouldn't recommend this, though!)

Comment: Yeah, it worked for some of my images, and did not work for image data stored in our database.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something to access the [exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data.  Google suggests [this library](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/).

Answer (score 0):

The code example below asks the user for a file path and then outputs the creation date and time:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            // get runtime environment and execute child process
            Runtime systemShell = Runtime.getRuntime();
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter filename: ");
            String fname=(String)br1.readLine();
            Process output = systemShell.exec("cmd /c dir /a "+fname);
             // open reader to get output from process
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(output.getInputStream()));

            String out="";
            String line = null;

            int step=1;
             while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) 
              {
                 if(step==6)
                {
                out=line;
                }
                 step++;
                 }          // display process output

            try{
            out=out.replaceAll(" ","");
            System.out.println("CreationDate: "+out.substring(0,10));
            System.out.println("CreationTime: "+out.substring(10,15));
            }
            catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException se)
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
            }
          catch (IOException ioe){ System.err.println(ioe); }
          catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, but I actually need to get the date from the picture metadata, not from the file system.